# Where do I need to switch the Activation Context?

Tags: winapi, com, side-by-side, regfreecom, activation-context-api

The problem I'm facing is essentially [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942999/move-manifest-file-to-dll), that is:

- I have a DLL that is using a 3rd party in-process COM component dll.
- I want to use registration free COM with that in-process component.
- I want to embed and use a manfest into this DLL (not into the main EXE) so that I can use the 3rd party component in a reg free way.
- The Interface I use from the component is activated through a call to `CoCreateInstance`.
- The 3rd party COM component hasn't got any further (COM) dependencies and doesn't rely on or need isolation.

I see that simply embedding a manifest into my DLL doesn't work, as as is described in the linked question, I will need to switch the [Activation Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) manually.

What I do not understand is *where* and when I need to switch the Activation Context: Do I only need to wrap my call to `CoCreateInstance` in something like [`CActCtxActivator ScopedContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375197.aspx)(*), or would I need to wrap all calls into the 3rd party component? <sub>(Which, as far as I understand is what [`ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2007/06/26/rt-manifest-resource-and-isolation-aware-enabled.aspx) is supposed to help with.)</sub>

So, when using registration free COM, where do you need to switch the [Activation Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

---

(*) : <strike>Or `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());`</strike>(**) or whatever.

---

(**): Actually, `AFX_MANAGE_STATE` used to work, but does no longer in "newer" MFC versions. See, e.g. [VS2012: Removed support for active contexts switching in MFC?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8ae4136c-622c-4afe-9db7-619baffb9501/vs2012-removed-support-for-active-contexts-switching-in-mfc?forum=vcgeneral):

> We removed all the activation context support from MFC because we
> ....  We use the Windows
> isolation aware APIs internally in MFC itself.
>
> // posted by: Pat Brenner, Visual C++ Libraries Development: Wednesday, June 05, 2013 11:10 PM

Comment: Wrapping `CoCreateInstance` suffices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to wrap your call to `CoCreateInstance`, given that the 3rd party component has no other dependencies.

If it had other dependencies, then you would need to wrap the calls into the 3rd party component.

Comment: "... then you would need to wrap the calls into the 3rd party ..." - that is to say, those calls that in themselves require the switched Activation Context, i.e. those calls that would trigger (something like) `CoCreateInstance` themselves and where I would want those dependencies be resolved via the switched context?

Comment: @MartinBa That's correct.  I assumed that you don't always know which calls would need the switched context, and that it's safest to wrap them all.